# Aligning div to baseline of the first line of another div?

Tags: css, vertical-alignment, baseline

I've got two divs and would like to align their baselines. However, one of the divs has more than one line of text and some embedded content, and while I'd like to align them to the top baselines, the browser seems to align to the bottom one.

I've built a JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/chk31vev/) to illustrate, with the following HTML:

```
<div style='display:inline-block;'>NOTE:</div>
<div style='display:inline-block; width:200px;'>
    Here's <div class='embedded'></div> an embedded div and more text
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
.embedded {
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:-15px;
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

What I'd like is this:

[image: Images aligned to bottom baseline]

What I get is this:

[image: Images aligned to top baseline]

A pure-CSS solution would be nice, but I'm not against using JavaScript here either. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it quite simply with a wrapping div and a bit of flex box.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: baseline;
}

.note {
  margin-right: 1ch;
}

.embedded {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: -15px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="note" style='display:inline-block;'>NOTE:</div>
  <div style='display:inline-block; width:200px;'>
      Here's <div class='embedded'></div> an embedded div and more text
  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: That works great! I'm trying to get the same to work with an old Webkit engine (we need to support wkhtmltopdf) using "display:-webkit-inline-box;" in the wrapper and "-webkit-box-align:baseline;" in the boxes. It works for some cases, but with two lines of text seems to be aligning to the bottom baseline again. Do you know if this is the expected behaviour for that standard?

Comment: I don't know. flex box implementation was all over the map for a while.

Answer (score 0):

```
This will solve your issue:    
 `<div style="display: flex;">
      <div style="padding-top: 13px;">NOTE: &nbsp;</div>
      <div>
        <p style="display:inline">
          Here's
          <span class='embedded'></span>
          an embedded div
          <br/> 
          and more text
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>`
```

Link :  [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/had1r03r/)